# Double Summation with a constant as the Summand

Tags: summation

As part of the preparation for an Exam, I'm working through a simple double sum exercise that has a constant as the Summand. The exercise has the answer (result) available but not the resolution. I attempted to solve it, but apparently I've reached a wrong answer.

**The question:**

*Calculate the following sum*: $$\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n 2$$

**My attempted resolution:**

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n 2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n \underbrace{(2 + 2 + \cdots + 2)}_{\text{n times}} = \sum_{i = 1}^n 2n = 2n \sum_{i = 1}^n 1  = 2n \times \underbrace{(1 + 1 + \cdots + 1)}_{\text{n times}} = 2n \times n = 2n^2$$

**The right answer:**

$$n^2 + n$$

What did I do wrong? How should I have solved this?

**EDIT:** Mistery solved! I had made a small but important mistake when I copied the question from the paper it was written. The lower limit of the inner sum is "j=i" ("j equals lowercase i") instead of "j=1" ("j equals one"). Thanks to everyone who commented ([T.Bongers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/61527/t-bongers), [Git Gud](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/55235/git-gud) and, particularly, [Mark Bennet](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2906/mark-bennet) who correctly guessed that I might have made a mistake in one of the limits).

Comment: No, you've done it correctly. There appears to be a mistake in the answer key.

Comment: The answer given to you fails for $n=2$.

Comment: Are you sure you've read the limits correctly in the original question - check that the upper limit of the inner sum is not $i$.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks for the tip! Actually, the upper limit of both sums is "n" (as I wrote), but the LOWER limit of the inner sum is "i" instead of 1 (so it's "j=i" instead of "j=1"). Good catch!

Comment: @ricmarques That's cunning of the examiner - but you'll be looking out for it come the real thing - which is the point of practice. One more trick you'll see through!